# Laravel Relate 2 models via intermediary table that has value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following schema

```sql
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     CREATE TABLE `attributes` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `records` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `event_school_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `athlete_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `year` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `place` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `records_event_school_id_foreign` (`event_school_id`),
      KEY `records_athlete_id_foreign` (`athlete_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `records_athlete_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`athlete_id`) REFERENCES `athletes` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `records_event_school_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`event_school_id`) REFERENCES `event_school` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `attribute_record` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `attribute_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `record_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `value` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `attribute_record_attribute_id_foreign` (`attribute_id`),
      KEY `attribute_record_record_id_foreign` (`record_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `attribute_record_attribute_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `attribute_record_record_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`record_id`) REFERENCES `records` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

How do I setup my models correctly in laravel? For attribute_record table there is a value that is present in the relationship between an attribute and a record. I am wondering if I need a model for the attribute_record table.

I want to be able to do something where I can have a $record get the attributes and their values.

```
foreach($record->attributes as $attr)
{
   echo $attr->value;
}
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Attribute extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Record extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if I need a model for the attribute_record table.

No, this is a pivot table and Laravel will transparently use it when you set up your relationships properly. I assume this is a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (records can have many attributes, and many records can have the same attribute) so define your relationships and Laravel does the rest:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Attribute extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function records()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\\App\\Record')
            ->withPivot('value')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}


<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Record extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\\App\\Attributes')
            ->withPivot('value')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Now within a controller you can do this:

```
$record = \App\Record::find($id);
foreach ($record->attributes as $attribute) {
    // $attribute is an instance of \App\Attribute
    // to access the values in the pivot table, use the pivot attribute
    echo $attribute->pivot->value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Record extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'attribute_record')
            ->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

Then you can access the values like this:

```php
foreach($record->attributes as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->pivot->value;
}
```

When you specify values using `withPivot` method, you can access them under `$relatedInstance->pivot->yourColumn`.

The pivot values are retrieved from the intermediate relation table (`attribute_record` in your example)